# make cmake_check_build_system error 1

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, cmake

I am trying to run the make command, but it says

```
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /h1/cs/Desktop/cmake/ME/build: No such file or directory
```

make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1

This is possibly caused because I used to keep my files in that directory, but I deleted that directory and I moved the source files, CMakeLists.txt, etc, basically everything, from the old to new directory. The new directory is ws/cs/cmake/ME. Yes, I tried to run make in that new directory, and the error above is what I got. Because the new directory has a massive number of sub-directories, I'm not sure which file I need to change so that it knows about the new directory Where in my new directory do I need to change the path, so I can then run make again?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete and start compiling from a new directory you will get an easy fix.. For other options try searching with combination of file and grep.

Answer (score 0):

Believe this is a CLion question.
I'm late to the party but, if someone's looking then -

1. delete the **cmake-build-debug** folder entirely from within the project.
2. select the folder saying your **<PROJECT_NAME>**, under which the **cmake-build-debug** folder was present originally, then right click and **Reload CMake Project**